# Evaluate the double integral by using polar coordinate

Tags: multivariable-calculus, volume

Determine the value of $\iint_D \sin(9x^2+4y^2)dA$ where D is the region enclosed by the ellipse $9x^2+4y^2=1$?

How can i evaluate it by changing the region to polar coordinate?

Comment: Do you mean $9x^2+4y^2=1$?

Comment: First introduce new variables $X=3x$ and $Y=2y$. Don't forget that currently you have $dA=dxdy$

Comment: @GoodDeeds sorry, yeah i mean this.

Comment: @YuriyS what about the region?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\mathrm{
x={r\over3}\cos\phi,\quad y={r\over2}\sin\phi\\
{\partial(x,y)\over\partial(r,\phi)}={r\over6}
}$$
The required integral is
$$\mathrm{
\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^1\sin(r^2){r\over6}\,dr\,d\phi\\
={1\over12}\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^1\sin(r)\,dr\,d\phi\\
={\pi\over6}(1-\cos1)
}$$

Comment: Well done. How you know that r from 0 to 1?

Comment: @chenarabdulla The interior of the ellipse is $0\le 9x^2+4y^2\le1$. Plug in the values of x,y in terms of $r,\phi$ to get $0\le r^2\le1$. Polar coordinates always assume $r\ge0$.